# Can we have a map like this in c++ >> map <vector<int>,vector<int>> m;

Tags: c++

Just a tought came in mind till now i have make maps of strings and vectors
Like this
`map<int,int> m; map <int,vector<int>> m; map <string,vector<int>> m;`
and various combinations are possible with other data types also.

But what will happen If I do
`map <vector<int>,vector<int>> m; or  map <vector<int>,vector<vector<int>>> m;`
etc.

I was solving a question leetcode in which this format could be helpfull
https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-90/problems/odd-string-difference/
I tried like this

```
class Solution {
public:
    string oddString(vector<string>& words) {
        map <vector<int>,vector<string>> m;
        for(auto i:words)
        {
            // m[{int(i[0]-i[1]), int(i[1]-i[2])}].push_back(i);
            vector<int> v;
            for(int j=1;j<i.size();j++)
            {
                v.push_back(int(i[j]-i[j-1]));
            }
        }
        for(auto i:m)
        {
            if(i.second.size() ==1)
            {
                return i.second[0];
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
};
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? You probably want to add an `int main()` so others can test. A Solution class alone is not a [mcve]

Comment: For what would it be helpful? What would it allow you to do? How would you use it and select one of the mapped vectors?

Comment: The value type basically is irrelevant; You may not be able to use the `[]` in some cases though. As for the key type: As long as the type is comparable with objects of the same type, you can use `std::map` with the default compare... `std::vector` implements the comparison operators...

Comment: Nothing special will happen, you will just have `std::vector<std::string>` as a key in a map. Default `operator<` for vector just compares all elements lexicographically. Doesn't sound efficient to me, but by all means you are allowed to use it.

Comment: This question's code/phrasing very likely came from one of many countless coding challenge/puzzle websites. They take advantage of people who want to learn C++ by offering coding puzzles based on arcane knowledge or programming tricks; combined with a claim that solving those useless coding puzzles makes anyone a C++ expert. This is untrue, of course, but these coding puzzles (that have no learning or real-world value) are unsolvable without certain, specific coding or math tricks. Everyone eventually figures out this scam, but only after a long time, with nothing to show it.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. It's the same problem as "given a vector of integers where all except one are the same, find the odd one out", but with "difference vectors" instead of integers.

Comment: *But what will happen If I do ... etc?*  Assuming the parameter types meets all the `map` requirements, **it'll just work.**

Comment: @sweenish The thing about C++ is that undefined behaviour means "I tried it, and got the result I expected" *doesn't* mean that what you did is supported by the language

Comment: @Caleth That's a good point. I suppose what I'd prefer is a question more along the lines of "Should I do this?" over "Can I do this?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use `std::vector<int>` as a key in `std::map` but you'll need take a look at the requirements for a given type to be used as a key in `std::map`.

From [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. **Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare.** Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black trees.

<sup>*Emphasis mine*</sup>

So the Key type must meet the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements.

By default, `std::map` uses `std::less<Key>`. `std::less<std::vector<int>>` or in other words `std::vector::operator<()` lexicographically compares the values in the vector.
If you want something else, you will have to provide your own compare function when instantiating the map:

```
std::map<std::vector<int>, my_value_type, my_compare_function> my_map; // Note the third parameter is the compare function.
```

***Note:** That being said, when we start to use containers as key type for a map, it often is a flag indicating a wrongly designed algorithm/software architecture.*

---

Regarding the value type in a `std::map`, you can have anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

[The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for std::map states that you can use any type you provide a *Compare()* function for it of that it has the *operator<*.

This is the case for vector, so it will work.

That said, you need to think about the problem you are trying to solve. I can't think about any problem where having a map of vector keys would be a good solution for.